# How do I restrict URLs to a specific wireless network?

Tags: security, wifi

Building my own authentification system at the moment and stumbled upon one idea:

How do schools/universities etc can restrict pages to only be accessible while being on the School's Wifi? What's the technique behind it? Basically: How can I make some pages only accessible while being on a specific WiFi?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They build their own network using own server which is not public facing which means it is not accessible through internet.

To access that network, you need to be connected to their server directly or using VPN(virtual private network).

If you want to make some pages only accessible while being on specific wifi(router). You need to create one of your computers as server and create a local network and other machines can join your network using password you will provide them. Other machines which will be clients have to be connected to same wifi

Answer (score 0):

They usually run on a server on the network behind a firewall so inaccessible from outside. I've built a few intranets for companies like this.

Clint.

Comment: Okay and if we talk about URLs which are only accessible when you are on the intranet, where do we define those?

Comment: You can do it a few ways I usually just edit the hosts file to point the domain I need to the servers ip. Usually a Linux apache server with the domains set up as virtual hosts.  https://www.devside.net/wamp-server/accessing-websites-on-a-local-network-lan-web-server

Answer (score 0):

Log-in to your router admin page and look for URL filters in setup options. Now, add the pages/sites you want to block.